# Magento - Create observer that sends email

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, event-observer

How can I write an observer that sends email which tracks an `eav_attribute` **yes** or **no** value?

The email get's sent, if value is set to yes.

I already created the attribute and the email template.

I only need help with the observer that sends email if the attribute is set to yes on the admin page for a particular user.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to send an email after the value of the attribute is set to "Yes", is that a customer attribute or product, category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send an email on data change of that attribute you can build an observer on the `customer_save_after Event`, were you want to check the old value and the newest one of the customer and if that changed from **NO** to **YES** since this will be triggered every time you'll save the customer.

> config.xml

```
<events>
     <customer_save_after>
         <observers>
            <vendor_module_customer_save_after>
                 <type>singleton</type>
                 <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                 <method>send</method>
            </vendor_module_customer_save_after>
          </observers>
      </customer_save_after>
</events>
```

Your `observer` with the send function inside:

```
function send($observer){

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

        $old = $customer->getOrigData('custom_attribute');
        $new = $customer->getData('custom_attribute');
        
        if($old == 0 && $new == 1){
    
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    $emailTemplate->loadDefault('template_name');
    
    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['name'] = $customer->getName();
    $emailTemplateVariables['email'] = $customer->getEmail();
    
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    
    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderEmail);
    
    $emailTemplate->send($senderEmail, $senderName, $emailTemplateVariables);
    
            // Do your stuff and call the email function
        } 
}
```

**Not sure about the part of the email send, but this should do the trick**